# Magento ver 1.9.x - uploaded image create extra

Tags: magento-1.9, product, upload

I am facing a problem with Magento ver. 1.9.x Image import is working fine but when I try to upload image it don't work. My cache is disabled and media folders is 777. I have added front end and back end screenshots for you to have a look.

Any help will be really appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Try to upgrade your adobe flash player

Comment: Thx zhartaunik, I also tried it.

Comment: Check firebug last tab. What do you see there?

Comment: firebug console create no error.

Comment: Do any files appear in your media folder? Even empty files? Is there enough space on server? Try to change server /tmp folder and check its permissions. Try to check server error log

Answer (score 1):

Please double check your media folder permission. Please enable cache and try once again.

Comment: thx Sham, I followed your instruction. Not yet solved. do you think is it db related issue or any thing else?.

Comment: when you upload image does it show any error? or simply add new row ther with no image?

Comment: simply added new row there with no image.

Comment: Whether your magento in local machine or server? I strongly doubt its related to permission.

Comment: Also try renaming your .htaccess file in media folder and your ownership of media folder too..

Comment: It's both. I strongly confirming you permission is ok.

Comment: I also tried renaming with .htaccess. I tried several way with googling.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have successfully uploaded your image via `magento` back-end but you have to choose base image, small and thumbnail in order your image to appear at the front-end. Give it a try.

Comment: First time product image save without selection base, small & thumb. And extra row create.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading image already done but only If you want to show this image in product listing page , you should active a radio button under 'Small Image' radio buttons list.
'Base Image': to show in product detail page.
'Thumbnail' : to show in cart page, side bar cart.